# HtmlAgilityPack Extract data

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

So, I'm like brand new to the HtmlAgilityPack, and I was wondering if someone could help me out with extracting this data, then explaining to me all the symbols involved and what they mean.

I want to extract a gift card balance (this is strictly for personal use, I'm thinking of doing like an Amazon account summary program) the HTML for that is as follows...

```
    <div class="gcBalanceBox ">
    <h3>Available Gift Card Balance:
        <span>$1.02</span>
    </h3>

        <p>Your balance will never expire. We'll automatically apply your balance when you checkout. If you would rather not use your balance, you can deselect it in the Payment Selection step of checkout.</p>
</div>
```

I want to extract the  data [$1.02] from this, here's what I tried with no success though:

```
 HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument hp = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            hp.LoadHtml(webBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerHtml);
            var node = hp.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='gcBalanceBox']/span");
            string Description = node.InnerText;
```

Could someone explain a solution to me please? Thank you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost there.

The span is inside the `<h3>`, though, so you would want to include that in your xpath:

```
var node = hp.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='gcBalanceBox ']/h3/span");
```

Comment: Ahh I feel so stupid, I still can't get my code working here though>>
` var node = hp.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='gcBalanceBox']/h3/span").InnerText;`

It throws:
` Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: Check if `webBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerHtml` actually contains something. It is also a good idea to check if `hp.DocumentNode != null` before the statement that is throwing the error as well.

Comment: Yes webBrowser1.Document.Body.Innerhtml does contain something, I wrote it to a text file before it tried anything and the HTML returned just as the webpage. So what could it be?

Comment: Is `webBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerHtml` exactly equal to the html that you have written in your question? Or is the html snippet you posted just a portion of it?

Comment: Found the issue, there was a space in the class name; i.e: 'gcBalanceBox '. Leave it to the Amazon coders. Thank you very much sir.